# Selecting columns names in data frame not found in character strings in r

Tags: r, string

I currently have ndat, a dataframe containing items and their respective data which looks like this:

```
> glimpse(ndat)
Observations: 203
Variables:
$ i5 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
$ i4 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
$ i3 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
$ i2 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2...
$ i1 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
```

I also have "newDV" and "newCV" which are character strings containing the item names of several of the items found in ndat, and look like:

```
> newCV
[1] "i3" "i2"
> newDV
[1] "i1"
```

What I am trying to do is get ndat to contain the items that are not contained in newCV or newDV so it ends up looking like:

```
> glimpse(ndat)
Observations: 203
Variables:
$ i5 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
$ i4 (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
```

I have tried the following:

```
ndat<-as.data.frame(ndat[!(ndat %in% c(newCV,newDV))])
```

But this appears to work only for character string to character string, and not using character strings to specify columns in data frames.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `ndat[,!(names(ndat) %in% c(newCV,newDV))]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg that worked feel free to suggest as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply filter by the column names of `ndat` instead of its values, e.g.

```
ndat[,!(names(ndat) %in% c(newCV, newDV))]
```